# Update: how to update patch versions like x.y-abc1?

Tags: install4j

We configured a standalone updater and need an update check for patch versions like 1.2-b01. I tried an update from 1.2 to 1.2-b01 without success. The updater displayed that we are up to date. Therefore the question: how does the check compares the version? Only major and minor or maybe only values separated by dots? I used:

```
((UpdateDescriptor)context.getVariable("updateDescriptor")).getPossibleUpdateEntry()
```

And if the update entry is null, no update is requiered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install4j replaces the "-" with a "." and assigns a negative weight to the version component "b01" that starts with a non-numeric character. This is done to support upgrades paths like

1.0-beta3 => 1.0

In your case

1.2 => 1.2-01patch

would work.

Comment: Okay. When I need to check a version like 1.2-b01 I have to implement a script comparing the version by iterating the `UpdateDescriptor` entries. Is that right? It's not possible to change the patch version suffix for our application.

Comment: Yes, that is another possibility.